# How Julia use Lufact to solve Ax=b

Tags: matrix, julia, decomposition, matrix-factorization

I want to recreate a solve function(solve Ax = b for x) for sparse matrix.
In the Julia documentation, it says that when we applied a sparse matrix to lufact(), it returns the following:

```
L, U, p, q, Rs = F[:(:)]
```

With the given formula in Julia doc: LU = Rs.*A[p,q], I did some algebra and obtained the following formula:

```
x = U \ ( L \ (Rs.*b[p]) )
ipermute!(x,q)
```

This formula matched with the default F\b solver in Julia when the matrix is dense but the result is off when the matrix is sparse. Does anyone know why?

Comment: care to give a specific example which fails?

Comment: It turns out the routine above is correct except for missing a bracket in the scaling factors. x = U \ ( L \ ((Rs.*b)[p]) )
ipermute!(x,q)

Answer (score 2):

`using LinearAlgebra`, then `B = lu(A); B\b`. Julia returns a type and its dispatch on `\` handles the rest.

Comment: Yes, but I want to develop my own solving routine using the factor (L,U,p,q,Rs)

Comment: Then check `@which B\b` and you'll get a link to the code.